# Cannot able to give space between Views in Horizontal ScrollView

Tags: android

main xml:

```
    <HorizontalScrollView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/navlayout"
        android:id="@+id/scroll"
        android:padding="0dp"> 

         <LinearLayout

            android:id="@+id/horizontallayout"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"

            android:orientation="horizontal"
             /> 

 </HorizontalScrollView>
```

Added layout:

```
 <RelativeLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                    android:id="@+id/fblayout1"
                    android:layout_width="300dp"

                    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                    android:background="@drawable/facebook1_texture"
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    android:padding="5dp" >

                    <RelativeLayout
                        android:id="@+id/navlayout1"
                        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

                        <ImageView
                            android:id="@+id/image"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                            android:src="@drawable/facebook_small" />

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/textheader1"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                            android:text="Facebook"
                            android:textColor="#ffffff"
                            android:textSize="20dp"
                            android:textStyle="bold" />

                        <ImageView
                            android:id="@+id/settings1"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                            android:background="@drawable/settins_icon"
                            android:visibility="gone" />

                        <ImageView
                            android:id="@+id/close1"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                            android:background="@drawable/cross_icon"
                            android:visibility="gone" />
                    </RelativeLayout>

                    <TextView

                        android:id="@+id/note1"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_below="@+id/navlayout1"
                        android:padding="5dp"
                        android:text="My Dashboard needs your permission to access your Facebook account before displaying your feed. Login below to give your permission. You will be sent to Facebook first to confirm this."
                        android:textColor="#ffffff"
                        android:textSize="18dp" />

                    <ListView
                        android:id="@+id/list1"
                        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                        android:layout_below="@+id/navlayout1"
                        android:padding="5dp"
                        android:visibility="gone">
                    </ListView>

                    <RelativeLayout
                        android:id="@+id/centerlayout1"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                        android:visibility="gone" >

                        <ImageView
                            android:id="@+id/fbimage1"
                            android:layout_width="100dp"
                            android:layout_height="100dp"
                            android:layout_centerInParent="true" />

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/text1"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_below="@+id/fbimage1"
                            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                            android:text="Facebook"
                            android:textColor="#ffffff"
                            android:textSize="15dp" />
                    </RelativeLayout>

                    <com.databoard.facebook.LoginButton
                        android:id="@+id/fb1"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                        android:background="@drawable/login_btn"
                        android:layout_marginBottom="20dp" />

                    <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/logout1"
                        android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                        android:background="@drawable/logout_btn"
                        android:padding="10dp"
                        android:visibility="gone" />
                </RelativeLayout>
```

code to add views:

```
      view= getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.fblayout, null);
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams llp=new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(400,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

  llp.setMargins(0, 0, 100, 0);
  view.setLayoutParams(llp);

  llTotal.addView(view);
```

The above code I used to add views to the Horizontal Scrollview,but I am not getting space between the views added.

I tried by giving padding to the Linearlayout and the Added xml,but it didnt worked for me.
 I didnt understand why the 
                  llp.setMargins(0, 0, 100, 0);
    is not working for my case.

Comment: Even I'm facing similar kinda problem. When I try to add only one view (either button or textview) programatically, even without setting margin or padding there is a space between the views. But only when I try to add a custom view (inflating from an xml file), there are no spaces between views. One way (or kinda workaround) is to add margin to all your child views.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem. I tried adding margin and padding everywhere and the children views of the HorizontalScrollView still will not have gaps between them.

In the end I used this workaround: In each child view, I used a LinearLayout and added "spacer" TextView element (TextView with spaces as text) before and after my "real" content. So that these spacer TextViews becomes the gap.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure I understand your code and what you are trying to achieve. You are adding the margin to the superview that was created from inflating `fblayout.xml`. If I understand your code correctly that should be the RelativeLayout. However, then you are adding that relativelayout to a `LinearLayout` in `main.xml`. Therefore having `RelativeLayout` params on a childview of `LinearLayout` is not going to work. 
To be honest I would have expected some exception since all child views always have layout params according to their immediate parent. So this means you would typically need to set `LinearLayout.LayoutParams` on the `view` variable in your code.

At any rate my proposal would be to configure the margin on the `RelativeLayout` in the xml.

```
 <RelativeLayout
     xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                android:id="@+id/fblayout1"
                android:layout_width="300dp"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
==>             android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"


                android:background="@drawable/facebook1_texture"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:padding="5dp" >
```

And remove the programmatic layout code. Havent tried this out but it should do the trick.

One thing you might consider is to use the Hierarchy Viewer in Eclipse and inspect the resulting view hierarchy on the device or emulator. At least then you can see which of your settings remain.

Finally, the last trick you can do is to build the whole layout statically in `main.xml` and configure it so that it looks the way you want. Only then you should start making it dynamic.

Answer (score 0):

Please set padding on added layout.

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/navlayout1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@android:color/darker_gray" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/image"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textheader1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:text="Facebook"
            android:textColor="#ffffff"
            android:textSize="20dp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/settings1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            android:visibility="gone" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/close1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            android:background="@drawable/cross_icon"
            android:visibility="gone" />
    </RelativeLayout>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/note1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/navlayout1"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:text="My Dashboard needs your permission to access your Facebook account before displaying your feed. Login below to give your permission. You will be sent to Facebook first to confirm this."
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:textSize="18dp" />

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/list1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_below="@+id/navlayout1"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:visibility="gone" >
    </ListView>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/centerlayout1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:visibility="gone" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/fbimage1"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/text1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/fbimage1"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:text="Facebook"
            android:textColor="#ffffff"
            android:textSize="15dp" />
    </RelativeLayout>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/fb1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
        android:background="@drawable/login_btn" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/logout1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:visibility="gone" />
</RelativeLayout>
```